# How to determine the number of constrained CPUs within a Docker container? For use with make -j

Tags: docker, limit, environment, gitlab-ci-runner

Docker supports a `--cpus` option which constrains a container to using a certain proportion of the host's computing resource. For example, `--cpus 2.5` will allocate computing resource equivalent to approximately two and a half of the host's CPU capability. This allocation seems to be somewhat "logical" rather than physical, in that a container running eight processes but with `--cpus 1.0` tends to run each process on a separate CPU but limited to approximately 12.5%. This is fine, I suppose.

The problem is that I am not able to find a way for a process within a constrained container to determine how many equivalent CPUs it has available. This is useful specifically for build processes, for example `make -j <n>`, but what is `n`? Commonly used `nproc` outputs the number of CPUs on the host regardless of the `--cpus` option value, which makes it unsuitable as it is far too large. The value of `/proc/cpuinfo` is also the host's view (same as `nproc`).

**Is there a way for a contained process to determine the number of CPUs available to it?**

As an example, on my 16-core host, I'd like to use `docker run ... --cpus 4.0 ...` and then have `make -j <something>` run *only four* processes rather than, say, sixteen.

FWIW, I'm using the Docker Executor with GitLab-CI and `gitlab-runner`, which is why `--cpuset-cpus=` isn't really helpful. The Executor should be able to allocate a number of CPUs to each job across all of the host's CPUs, rather than a specific subset. Although I could create separate Executors for, say, each explicit set of four CPUs, there's no obvious way I'm aware of for `gitlab-runner` to allocate these in a balanced way to incoming jobs, and I want to avoid pushing the responsibility onto the jobs themselves, perhaps using **tags** to select an Executor, since that would require each job to know too much about the runner.

I did consider setting a corresponding environment variable like `NUM_CPUS=4` in the `gitlab-runner`'s `config.toml` so that the build job can find out how many to use with `make -j $NUM_CPUS`, however variables in `config.toml` can only be set for all runners, not individual ones:

```
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "build"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  executor = "docker"
  environment = ["NUM_CPUS=4"]
  [runners.docker]
    # ...
    cpus = "4"    # match NUM_CPUS!
    environment = ["FOO=456"]
```

The container's environment will see `NUM_CPUS=4` but the statement to effect `FOO=456` is invalid and of course no such value appears in the container's environment, which makes it impossible to vary the value between Executors.

I should add that in the near future I want to create Executors with different numbers of CPUs - for example, one with just one CPU for simple single-process jobs, and another with lots of CPUs for intensive multi-process jobs, and the GitLab-CI jobs will be able to pick these using GitLab-CI **tags**. I specifically want to avoid the situation where the pipeline jobs explicitly state that they are to use exactly, say, 4 CPUs, since that requires the jobs to know too much about the build environment and makes it brittle.

Comment: I also have this problem, with the added wrinkle of the runners being in a k8s cluster and a range of CPU units (request ... limit), so what is a good value is determined at runtime (i.e., the OP's workaround won't work for us).